# why I get C6001 warning in my merge sort?

Tags: c++, merge

I have written code below but I get warning C6001: using uninitialized memory
in merge function before last line at  `arr[z] = S[z]` , I have used dynamic array because VS-2022 don't support VLA.
I have seen different types of merge algorithms but I want this specific code to run because I am using an instruction  that  I have to follow for my project!

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void merge(int*, int, int, int);
void merge_sort(int*, int, int);
void printArrey(int*, int);
int main()
{
    int arr[9] = { 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 };
    printArrey(arr, 9);
    merge_sort(arr, 0, 8);
    printArrey(arr, 9);
    system("pause");
}

void merge(int* arr, int start, int mid, int end)
{
    int i = start, j = mid+1, k = start;
    int* S = new int[end+1];
    while (i <= mid && j <= end)
    {
        if (arr[i] < arr[j]) 
        {
            S[k] = arr[i];
            i++;
        }
        else 
        {
            S[k] = arr[j];
            j++;
        } 
        k++;
    }
    if (i > mid) 
    { 
        for (; j <= end; k++, j++) 
        { 
            S[k] = arr[j];  
        } 
    }
    else if (j > end) 
    { 
        for (; i <= mid; k++, i++) 
        { 
            S[k] = arr[i];  
        } 
    }
    for (int z=0; z < k; z++) 
    { arr[z] = S[z]; }

    delete[] S;
}

void merge_sort(int* arr, int start, int end)
{
    if (start < end)
    {
        int mid = start+ (end - start) / 2;
        merge_sort(arr, start, mid);
        merge_sort(arr, mid+1, end);
        merge(arr, start, mid, end);
    }
}

void printArrey(int* arr, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I searched the internet for "C6001" and got this page: [MS C6001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6001?view=msvc-170).  Maybe, just maybe, searching first before asking can produce quality information.

Comment: Note that in `merge_sort`, your loop `while(start < end)` will be an endless loop because nothing you do inside it will change `start` or `end`.

Comment: You populate `S` from `start` to `end`, but read it from 0 to `k` at the end. These are don't seem to necessarily be the same ranges. If start is anything other than `0`, then the first read of the loop will be to uninitialized memory.

Comment: I have searched as much as it was possible, and I am here because I was totally stuck and clueless. I have checked every thing multiple times but I couldn't figure out what to do, that is why I am here now!

Comment: Why should the `while` in `merge_sort` terminate? Nothing in the body changes `start` or `end`... Are you sure `mid = (end - start)/2` gives you an index between `start` and `end`? What is the result with `start=10` and `end=14`?

Comment: yeah, that should be if instead of while, tnx

Comment: The non-overflowing midpoint is `start + (end-start)/2`, as @6502 already noted, you're missing the `start + ` portion of that calculation.

Comment: omg, it is working now, but still needs to be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I had to use

```
while(start<=end)
    {
        arr[start] = S[start];
        start++;
    }
```

instead of

```
for (int z=0; z < k; z++) 
    { arr[z] = S[z]; }
```

tnx to anyone who helped!

Comment: Note that all of the memory from `S[0]` to `S[start]` is still just sitting there not being at all.  Ideally, you'd want to use `int* S = new int[end-start];` and use `S[x-start]` instead of `S[x]` accross the board.